# How can I number corollary as a child of theorem where the latter is a child of section using tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want a result that looks like:

> 1 Section
>
> Theorem 1.1
>
> Corollary 1.1.1
>
> Proposition 1.2
>
> Corollary 1.2.1
>
> ...

This can be achieved easily using amsthm as I used to. However, I want to use tcolorbox for my new notes now but I just cannot find the command that allows me to put three numbers in the title. I searched around and the following is the best I get:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\newcounter{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{before title={\stepcounter{theo}}}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=theo]{corollary}{Corollary}{}{cor}

\begin{document}
\section{testSection}
\begin{theorem}{testTitle}{}
test theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}{testTitle}{}
test corollary
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe you should add `use counter=theo` in the optional argument of the Theorem (and you can remove the `\stepcounter`): `\newtcbtheorem[use counter=theo,number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{th}`.

Comment: @campa That works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @campa Would you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Rather not. I never used `tcolorbox` in my life and I cannot really believe that it provides no way to access the *real* counter. Hopefully some expert will provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner counter name has prefix `tcb@cnt@` (check the example of key `/tcb/new/auto counter` in `tcolorbox`'s user manual), hence with

```tex
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{<options>}{th}
```

the `theorem` environment will use counter `tcb@cnt@theorem`. Therefore what you need is

```tex
\newtcbtheorem[number within=tcb@cnt@theorem]{corollary}{Corollary}{}{cor}
```

#### Full example

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=tcb@cnt@theorem]{corollary}{Corollary}{}{cor}

\begin{document}
\section{testSection}
\begin{theorem}{testTitle}{}
test theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}{testTitle}{}
test corollary
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

[image]